# Linear Algebra Proof Using Dimensions and Subspaces with Kernel and Image

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let X and Y be vector spaces, let $n \in N$, and suppose that $X$ is $n$-dimensional
>   Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of $X$ and $Y$ respectively such that $dim(V ) = dim(X) − dim(U)$.
>
> Prove that there exists a linear transformation $T: X \rightarrow Y$ such that $ker(T) = U$ and $im(T) = V$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_1,...,e_k$ be a base for $U$ and let $Te_i =0$ for $i\leq k$.

Let $e_{k+1},...,e_n$ be the rest of a base for $X$ and let $f_{k+1},...,f_n$ be a base for $V$

Also let  $Te_i = f_i$ for $i\geq k+1$. Then this linear transformation will do the job.

Comment: Thank you! Using your suggestions I figured out how to prove this. Do you know if this transformation is unique? If so how would you prove it?

Comment: I would not say it is uniqe, since we can choose basis on many different ways.

Comment: Just did. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you!..........